# How to analyse newman htmlextra report?

Tags: test-report, postman

Hi could someone explain the fields in Postman htmlextra report. I am not able to understand why testscripts fail shows '0' even though two assertions failed

1. I only have 15 pm.expect in my testscripts but assertion shows as 19.
2. Failed test shows as 2 but in summary testscripts shows fail as 0
3. How to know total no of scenarios covered (No:of tests ) from this
   report.

[image: Newman Htmlextra report]

Also, why the count shows as two in the total request tab for the below scripts even though it was ran only for 1 iteration. How is this count changed ?

[image]

Comment: The count in test information was showing as 2 because i had pre-request script. But does not make any sense as that was not under pm.test()

Comment: Please put useful comment when downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only have 15 pm.expect in my testscripts but assertion shows as 19.

Assertions in postman actually means what ever inside pm.test and not just all pm.expect. So total number of assertion is the total number of testcases.

> Failed test shows as 2 but in summary testscripts shows fail as 0

Testscripts are marked as failed when there is compilation or runtime errors for the scripts under tests tab. For instance, undeclared variables in the scripts

> How to know total no of scenarios covered (No:of tests ) from this
>   report.

Total number of assertions gives total number of test cases

> why the count shows as two in the total request tab for the below
>   scripts even though it was ran only for 1 iteration. How is this count
>   changed ?

This includes the pre request script + pm.test

Comment: Hey @PDHide, the fastest way to get all your questions answered would be to raise them on the reporter GH repo - I created it so I would be able to tell you what those things mean. By asking a question here, you're just sending it out to _anyone_ 

Comment: @DannyDainton Thanks Danny for the awesome report , you meant to raise a issue or contact through community support. ? I really feel confused why tests are marked as total assertion and but failed ones are marked as total test failed . If it was total assertion and failed assertion or , total tests and failed tests then it would have made more sense

Comment: You can raise an issue with a bunch of questions on the repo or get me through the support, either way really. :) The data is all coming through from Newman and those specific values are presented in a similar way as the CLI summary table. The reporter also takes custom template so if it doesn't make sense to you, you always have the ability to display that in a more meaningful way. :)